# How to do Apple Music-like navigation in SwiftUI? Custom List and NavigationView has highlight not going away

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

This is my example that I am trying to get to work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let links = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Text("My Title")
                List(links, id: \.self) {
                    link in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
                        Text(link)
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 178)
                Text("Some more content here")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: TestView is just some view with the text hello world on it.

I am trying to copy Apple Music's style of navigation. I tried putting a `Button` in the `NavigationLink` but tapping it on the text wouldn't change views, and I couldn't find a way to reliably change the color of the row when tapped, at the same time. Also in some approach, I managed to make it work, but the way the colors animate is different, i.e. it fades from A to B, over ~100ms whereas what I'm trying to achieve is to animate between the states instantly (like in Apple Music).

My current approach is using a `List`, putting `NavigationLinks` inside it and then cutting off the whole view by giving it a height. This way I can put it alongside other content.

It's working fine for now, but whenever I click on an row and go back, the row is still highlighted, when it shouldn't. Is there a way to make it so that it deselects when going back to the screen somehow?

I think this bug is being caused by the `List` being inside a `ScrollView`, since when I removed `ScrollView`, the list worked properly, and there wasn't this highlight bug. But I need to be able to put my content with the list, and I don't intend to have a list take up the whole screen.

Is there any way to fix this bug with this approach? I'm also willing for other ways to achieve the same result without using `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use `ForEach` instead of`List`?
With a view for row (CustomRow) where you can pass *link* item and set custom dividing line, background etc ...

```swift
ForEach(links, id: \.self) { link in
    NavigationLink(destination: TestView()) {
       CustomRow(item: link)
    }
  }
.frame(height: 178)
```